# Connection conrol MySQL on RDS

Tags: mysql, rds

I am trying to implement a connecton control/login failure audit on MySQL RDS instance but my MySQL CONNECTION_CONTROL PLUGIN isn't capturing and storing the attempted login failures.

I installed the plugin using the following commands:
INSTALL PLUGIN CONNECTION_CONTROL
  SONAME 'connection_control.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN CONNECTION_CONTROL_FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS
  SONAME 'connection_control.so';

They completed with no errors. I run the following query and both plugins are active.
SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS
       WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'connection%';

But when login attempt fails, no data will be insert into CONNECTION_CONTROL_FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS table. I tested this feature on my on-premise instances as well as EC2 instances and it's working fine but for some reason, failed login attempts will not be captured and stored on MySQL RDS instance. is this feature limitation? Any ideas? workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.Options.html I think not all plugins are supported. Try to these plugins.
I think you are looking for this option **SERVER_AUDIT_EVENTS**